# URL Fetch not working in Java 8 Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-8, google-cloud-platform

This may manifest as a Socket API quota error or the following exceptions: java.net.UnknownHostException, java.net.SocketTimeoutException, java.io.IOException.

Answer (score 0):

To continue using the URL Fetch API instead of the native Java 8 methods, you’ll have to add the following line to your appengine-web.xml:

```
 <url-stream-handler>urlfetch</url-stream-handler>
```

For more information, see [Issuing Requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/issue-requests#url_fetch_and_java_7java_8_runtime_compatibility).

For tips on migrating to Java 8 on Google App Engine, see
[Migrating to Java 8](https://cloud-dot-devsite.googleplex.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8).